# How to make a Global Variable with User Input?

Tags: javascript

I am making a program where I have a user input where the user types in their cat's name, and then I want the name to appear in the text throughout the program. Here is my code, it is in Javascript:

```
var catName = getText("nameInput");
onEvent("startBtn", "click", function(event) {
  setScreen("feedingScreen");
  setText("feedingText", catName+" is hungry! Give "+catName+" some food! 
Click fish to feed.");
});
```

Whwn I run this program, however, the cat name does not appear in the text. How can I make it where the text does show up?

Comment: What's the current scope in which you're defining `catName`? Try `windows.catName = 'kitty'`

Comment: assuming `getText()`, `onEvent()`, `setScreen()` and `setText()` functions are done right and that `startBtn` event is correctly emited, I think, the `getText()` function might be called too early. Try putting that line inside the callback (one line down).

Answer (score 0):

If the `catName` variable is going to be used for a long time, I'd consider using `localStorage` to store it and retrieve it whenever I want (even when the user leaves the page and comes back).

Example :

```
function setCatName(name) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('catName', name);
}

function getCatName() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('catName');
}
```

If you don't want that though, you could store it in the `window` object. Take note that it's considered bad practice (but so are global variables in general).

Example :

```
function setCatName(name) {
    window.catName = name;
}

function getCatName() {
    return window.catName;
}
```

### UPDATE :

It's funny because the examples on Mozilla's Docs use localStorage to set and retrieve a cat's name too :

[localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)